# Finding the list of checked item in list of lists

Tags: wpf, xaml

Let's say I have a questionnaire app, which consists of an ItemsControl with a list of controls each consisting of a Label and a ListBox.  The items in each ListBox are checkboxes or radiobuttons or whatever.

My question is: When a checkbox is checked, how do I figure out which Question the checkbox applies to?  Should I put a reference to the Question in the Tag property?  If so, how would I do that?

The Tag binding code below doesn't work.  It binds to the ListBoxItem.  How do I bind it to the ItemsControl item?

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="ListWithinListTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
  <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <Style x:Key="ConditionCheckBoxListStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Multiple" />
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
          <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" >
              <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
              <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Mode=TwoWay}"
                              Click="CheckBoxClicked"
                              Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                              >
                      <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                    </CheckBox>
                  </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
            </Style>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Window.Resources>

  <Grid>
    <ItemsControl Name="QuizControl" ItemsSource="{Binding QuizQuestions}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Margin="10 0 10 10" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Label Content="{Binding Text}" />
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Options}"
                     DisplayMemberPath="Text"
                     Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                     Style="{StaticResource ConditionCheckBoxListStyle}"
                     />
          </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace ListWithinListTest
{
    public class Option
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; } = false;
    }

    public class Question
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public Option[] Options { get; set; }
    }

    public class ViewModel
    {
        public Question[] QuizQuestions { get; set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            QuizQuestions = new Question[] {
                new Question { Text = "How are you?", Options = new Option[] { new Option { Text = "Good" }, new Option { Text = "Fine" } } },
                new Question { Text = "How's your dog?", Options = new Option[] { new Option { Text = "Sleepy" }, new Option { Text = "Hungry" } } },
            };
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ViewModel viewModel;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = viewModel = new ViewModel();
        }

        private void CheckBoxClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Question question = viewModel.QuizQuestions[???];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have binded QuizQuestions to the QuizControl, you can get it back from the ItemsSource property.

```
var  questions = (Question[]) QuizControl.ItemsSource;
```

**EDIT**

It looks like you got the answer yourself, just another way I would like to suggest to your original question:

Create one more property to your Option class

```
public class Option
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; } = false;
    public int Index{ get; set; }
}
```

And then add Index to each of your question options.

```
QuizQuestions = new Question[] {
            new Question { Text = "How are you?", Options = new Option[] { new Option { Text = "Good", Index = 0 }, new Option { Text = "Fine", Index = 0 } } },
            new Question { Text = "How's your dog?", Options = new Option[] { new Option { Text = "Sleepy", Index = 1 }, new Option { Text = "Hungry", Index = 1 } } },
};
```

In your CheckBox event you can get the Option Index

```
private void CheckBoxClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var s = (CheckBox)sender;
    var op = (Option)s.Tag;
    Question question = viewModel.QuizQuestions[op.Index];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I do need to know the exact Question object that it comes from.  I added an edit that said I didn't need that, but it turns out I do need it, so I removed it.  Sorry about my confusion.  Thanks for the response!

Comment: Actually the better way to do this is to make your ViewModel public and then you can retrieve the QuizQuestions array from the model later in the code.

Comment: I fixed the code so I can get the ViewModel, but I STILL need to find the question! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I messed with the Live Visual Tree window until, by process of elimination, I realized that the ListBox is what the Question is going to be bound to.  I know now that's a big duh, but that's where I am with this.  Then I used RelativeSource AncestorType to find it and the DataSource property to get the question:

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Mode=TwoWay}"
                          Click="CheckBoxClicked"
                          Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}"
                          >
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
    private void CheckBoxClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)sender;
        ListBox listBox = (ListBox)checkBox.Tag;
        Question question = (Question)listBox.DataContext;
        Debug.WriteLine(question.Text);
    }
```